# Renaming custom styles in excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have several template styles with a generic prefix used in their naming convention e.g. "My_Input", "My_Calculation" etc

I am trying to write some VBA code to change the prefix used for this naming convention in order to tailor the styles towards individual project, e.g. for project ABC I would like to be able to rename the styles as "ABC_Input", "ABC_Calculation".

The following code is my attempt so far but causes a compile error stating the following:
"Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment". Is this due to the fact that it is not possible to reassign this property or am I just missing something else?

```
Sub RenameStyles()
   Dim iStyleCount As Integer
   Dim strStyleName, strNewPrefix, strOldPrefix As String

   strNewPrefix = InputBox("Enter the desired style prefix")
   strOldPrefix = InputBox("Enter the current style prefix")

   For iStyleCount = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Count
      If ActiveWorkbook.Styles(iStyleCount).Name Like strOldPrefix & "*" Then
         strStyleName = ActiveWorkbook.Styles(iStyleCount).Name
         ActiveWorkbook.Styles(iStyleCount).Name = strNewPrefix & Right(strStyleName, Len(strStyleName) - Len(strOldPrefix)) 'THIS LINE CAUSES THE ERROR
      End If
   Next iStyleCount
End Sub
```

Cheers

Comment: What happens if you try: `ActiveWorkbook.Styles(iStyleCount).Name = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Styles(iStyleCount).Name, strOldPrefix , strNewPrefix , , 1)`? Side note: you should `Dim` variables like this: ` Dim strStyleNameAs String, strNewPrefixAs String, strOldPrefix As String` other wise only the last one is a string

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad unfortunately that code still returns the same error message but cheers for the pointer on the variable declarations!